# How do I access a certain list entry in a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
thisdict = {
  "brand": "Ford",
  "model": [1,4,9,16],
  "year": 1964
}

print(thisdict.get("model"[1]))
```

Comment: This seems to be a case of misplaced parentheses:  `print(thisdict.get("model")[1])`

Comment: YES, THANK YOU. I'm kinda new to dicts and this small thing has been taking up my time, as I was struggling to find any search results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try simply indexing -

```
thisdict['model'][1]
```

OR

```
thisdict.get('model')[1]
```

Comment: glad to help, do mark the solution if it helped you as it encourages me to help you in the future again :)

Answer (score 0):

When combining data structures, you must use each separately.

So, first get the list from the dict: `thisdict["model"]` or `thisdict.get("model")`.

Then, use the list: `thisdict.get("model")[1]`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I appreciate it a lot!